# Blackberry HttpConnection Timing Out

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to grab an XML file for parsing with the following:

```
private void getAndParseXML( String _xmlurl ) {
        HttpConnection xmlcon = null;
        InputStream input     = null;
        SAXParserFactory spf  = null;

        try {
            xmlcon = (HttpConnection)Connector.open( _xmlurl, Connector.READ ); // open connection to XML source
            spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();                               // set up xml parsers
            input = xmlcon.openInputStream();                                   // set up input stream

            SAXParser saxparser = spf.newSAXParser();   // create a new parser object
            saxparser.parse( input, this );             // parse operations start here
        }
        catch( IOException ex ) {
            System.out.println( "IOException Caught:\t" + ex.getMessage() ); // set a default item if any exception occurs with retreiving or parsing XML file
        }
        catch (SAXException ex) {
            System.out.println( "SAXException Caught:\t" + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( IllegalArgumentException ex ) {
            System.out.println( "IllegalArgumentException Caught:\t" + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            System.out.println( "ParserConfigurationException Caught:\t" + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            if ( input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();  // attempt to close all connections

                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if ( xmlcon != null ) {
                try {
                    xmlcon.close();
                }
                catch ( IOException ex ) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } // END ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But the I get an exception thrown saying the connection timed out after 12 seconds.  This after the line `input = xmlcon.openInputStream();` is executed.

If this is relevant, it is the IOException that gets caught, and determining if there is an active network connection is done before this method is called.  Did I miss something?

EDIT:  Just for clarification, this would be the first instance of a network connection in the application.  Before this block of code, a simple test:

```
private boolean isConnectedToNetwork() {

        boolean isConnected = false;

        if ( (TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR)) || (TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI)) )
            if ( (TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR)) || (TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI)) )
                isConnected = true;

        return isConnected;
    }
```

to make sure a connection would be possible, before attempting to retrieve an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  The url, in this case `_xmlurl`, needed to be appended with `";deviceside=true"` to ensure a direct TCP/IP connection was established.  This makes sure an HttpConnection is made through the cellular network.  In other words, to make sure the connection was not made through the Blackberry MDS.

Also, a check was needed:

```
if ( (TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI)) && (TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI)) )
```

the wi-fi antenna was on.  If the above ervaluated to true, the url (again `_xmlurl`) needed to be further appended with `";interface=wifi"` to avoid the cellular network , but still open a direct TCP/IP connection.

Answer (score 1):

Mike, everything looks OK.

However here are some ideas to think of:

1. Can you open the URL from your browser?
2. What BB Transport do you use to open the connection (for instance, maybe it fails on BES, but will work Ok on Direct TCP or Wi-Fi)?
3. By the moment of this call, have the code that "determins if there is an active network connection" closed all connections it might have opened (if any) during detection?

Comment: Yes the URL can opened in a browser.  I am not sure what you mean by BB Transport.

Comment: I have not set to run on BES (unless that is a default).  It should only be TCP/IP via cell antenna or wi-fi.  In this application, this would be the first instance where a connection would be opened.

Comment: OK, I see you are using only DirectTCP or WiFi BB Transports. Well, I don't see anything that might prevent this to work over WifI, while DirectTCP might have some issues (for instance, some providers may restric traffic by setting max allowed amount of data sent over a connection). So my advice would be to force WiFi usage to see how it works using WiFi BB Transport only.

Comment: BB Network Transports - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Network-Transports/ta-p/482457

Comment: Still times out.  But, at the same time, the test device (wifi only - no SIM card) I have won't even display google.com, and the browser in simulator (9800) doesn't even come to the foreground when I click the icon.  I'm beginning to suspect there are other issues here.